# How can you determine the number of events that have occurred over specified number of days using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I a have tibble with three columns:

1. runner - character string representing runners name
2. race - a numeric value representing the number of races run
3. date - the date of the race

I would like to add a fourth column, last45d, that represents the number of races that have been run in the last 45 days compared to the date of the current row. My reprex includes sample data and my attempt at producing the new row (i get all NAs).

reprex:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(reprex)

df<-tibble(runner=c("D.Wottle","D.Wottle","D.Wottle","D.Wottle","D.Wottle","D.Wottle","C.Hottle","C.Hottle","C.Hottle","C.Hottle","C.Hottle","C.Hottle","JJ.Watt","JJ.Watt","JJ.Watt","JJ.Watt","JJ.Watt","JJ.Watt"),
           race=c(6,5,4,3,2,1,6,5,4,3,2,1,6,5,4,3,2,1),
           date=c(ymd('20170625'),ymd('20170524'),ymd('20170420'),ymd('20170329'),ymd('20170308'),ymd('20170215'),ymd('20170625'),ymd('20170524'),ymd('20170410'),ymd('20170329'),ymd('20170304'),ymd('20170215'),ymd('20170615'),ymd('20170524'),ymd('20170428'),ymd('20170329'),ymd('20170301'),ymd('20170225')),
           surface=c('T','T','D','T','D','T','T','T','D','T','D','T','T','T','D','T','D','T'),
           distance=c(1400,1400,1600,1400,1500,1400,1400,1400,1600,1400,1500,1400,1400,1400,1600,1400,1500,1400),
           finish=c(1,2,2,1,2,3,2,3,3,2,1,1,3,1,1,3,3,2)

           )

df <- df %>% 
  group_by(runner) %>% 
  mutate(last45 = map_int(date, ~ sum(between(as.numeric(difftime(.x, date, units = "days")), 1e-9, 90)))) %>%
  ungroup()
df
#> # A tibble: 18 x 7
#>    runner    race date       surface distance finish last45
#>    <chr>    <dbl> <date>     <chr>      <dbl>  <dbl>  <int>
#>  1 D.Wottle     6 2017-06-25 T           1400      1      3
#>  2 D.Wottle     5 2017-05-24 T           1400      2      3
#>  3 D.Wottle     4 2017-04-20 D           1600      2      3
#>  4 D.Wottle     3 2017-03-29 T           1400      1      2
#>  5 D.Wottle     2 2017-03-08 D           1500      2      1
#>  6 D.Wottle     1 2017-02-15 T           1400      3      0
#>  7 C.Hottle     6 2017-06-25 T           1400      2      3
#>  8 C.Hottle     5 2017-05-24 T           1400      3      3
#>  9 C.Hottle     4 2017-04-10 D           1600      3      3
#> 10 C.Hottle     3 2017-03-29 T           1400      2      2
#> 11 C.Hottle     2 2017-03-04 D           1500      1      1
#> 12 C.Hottle     1 2017-02-15 T           1400      1      0
#> 13 JJ.Watt      6 2017-06-15 T           1400      3      3
#> 14 JJ.Watt      5 2017-05-24 T           1400      1      4
#> 15 JJ.Watt      4 2017-04-28 D           1600      1      3
#> 16 JJ.Watt      3 2017-03-29 T           1400      3      2
#> 17 JJ.Watt      2 2017-03-01 D           1500      3      1
#> 18 JJ.Watt      1 2017-02-25 T           1400      2      0
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

This is what I'd like the end result to look like:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```r
df %>%
  group_by(runner) %>%
  mutate(
    last45 = map_int(date, ~ sum(between(as.numeric(difftime(.x, date, units = "days")), 1e-9, 45)))
    #                ^^^^1                                       ^^^^2
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 6 x 4
#   runner    race date       last45
#   <chr>    <dbl> <date>      <int>
# 1 D.Wottle     6 2017-06-25      1
# 2 D.Wottle     5 2017-05-24      1
# 3 D.Wottle     4 2017-04-20      2
# 4 D.Wottle     3 2017-03-29      2
# 5 D.Wottle     2 2017-03-08      1
# 6 D.Wottle     1 2017-02-15      0
```

Notes:

- the two references to `date` are different: "1" (outside the tilde-function) is transferred into `.x` one at a time, so `.x` will always be a single date; "2" (inside the tilde-function) is the original column of dates, so will have as many values as the current runner has rows; and
- I use `1e-9` because if I use `0`, then the current day is always considered; by using `1e-9` (or some equally small number), we get the effective `(lower,upper]` bounds, vice the `dplyr::between` default of `[lower,upper]` (both sides closed).

Comment: thank you. I'm going to have to do a little research to understand what's going on with that mutate function, but I appreciate the opportunity to learn. Is this the same tilde function one would use to perform a regression analysis or use in a case_when.

Comment: What is 1e - 9?

Comment: The "tilde function" is mostly just shorthand, enabled by the tidyverse. think of `~` as `function(...)` where the `...` varies by its user, such as `function(.x)` for `map`, and `function(.x, .y)` for `map2`. `1e-9` is scientific notation for a really-small-number, as I discussed in the note, I use it because `dplyr::between` has both ends of the comparison "closed" (in mathematic notation sense). (Feel free to replace `1e-9` with `0.000000001`.)

Comment: Thanks again, I really appreciate it.  If wanted to add additional criteria, for example, how many races in the last 45 days, at a distance == 1400 meters, and finish position ==1. Would that be possible under the same construct? I've updated the tibble if you are so inclined.

Comment: Yup, look up `&`, the vectorized "AND" inline operator, documented under [`?&`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/Logic.html) (that page includes `&`, `&&`, `|`, `||`, and some others). For instance, `~ sum(between(...) & dist >= 1400 & pos == 1L)`. (I think that might work, though it'll do a bit more comparison than strictly necessary. If you're doing this with "large" amounts of data, perhaps 1M rows or more, then there might be some ways to short-circuit things.

Comment: I assumed I would need to use map2 or pmap, I'm going to have to draw this out to understand why thats not the case.

Comment: You don't, technically, since it doesn't need to be a row-wise comparison with the whole column. It might be simpler (and more efficient), though, to do `sum(map_lgl(date, ~ between(difftime(.x, date, units="days"), 1e-9, 45)) & dist >= 1400 & pos == 1)`, where the dist and pos conditionals are outside the call to `map`. Does that make more sense? (It does to me, in hindsight.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213845/discussion-between-mutuelinvestor-and-r2evans).